# am having a problem when using NeumorphicAppBar in flutter

Tags: flutter

am working with "flutter_neumorphic: ^3.0.3" package and am having a problem when i try to use NeumorphicAppBar [image: where i used the widget]

[image]

the Error message:
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building NeumorphicAppBar(dirty, dependencies: [_ModalScopeStatus, _InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#61b7d]], state: NeumorphicAppBarState#ad319):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
NeumorphicAppBar file:///D:/most%20important%20stuf/projects/flutter/fixing_todo_app/lib/screens/first_screen.dart:27:21
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      NeumorphicAppBarState.build (package:flutter_neumorphic/src/widget/app_bar.dart:238:66)
#1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: Can you provide us the full error message?

Comment: i added the error message